# SchemaCrawler creates a blank diagram

Tags: postgresql, graphviz, schemacrawler

Im not sure what the problem is with my command. im on windows and running the following script

```
-server=postgresql -host=localhost -port=5433 -database=test -schemas=public -tables=Tables -user=houdidi -password=test1234! -infolevel=maximum -command=schema -outputformat=pdf -outputfile=database-diagram.pdf %*
```

my postgresql structure tree looks like this:

```
database/test/schemas/public/Tables
```

im trying to create a diagram of all the tables inside the database `test` but it the PDF file created is blank. not sure where the problem is...

Comment: Please add more details, as described on [the SchemaCrawler website](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/consulting.html)

Comment: Also, take out `-tables=Tables`

Comment: im using the latest version of Schemacrawler and graphviz. i installed everything today...i got a postgresql 9.3 db with about 200 tables for which im trying to create a diagram because i inherited this and want to understand the relationship better. but the database-diagram.pdf that is created does not contain any data when i open it...what other information would be useful to provide?

Comment: Did you try without `-tables=Tables`? Please run the same command with an additional `-loglevel=ALL`, and zip and attach the logs.